# RESTeasy Name Binding Annotation Error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly-10

I'm trying to bind a name to a filter in JAX-RS so I can secure some methods in the rest service as the following:

**Secured Name Binding:**

```
@NameBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Secured {
}
```

**Authentication Filter:**

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationAgent implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
         //do something
    }
}
```

However, eclipse is giving me this error when I'm adding the secured annotation to my filter.

> There is no JAX-RS application, resource or resource method with this
>   name binding annotation.

[image]

Comment: Pretty smart editor. Name Binding should only be used when you want to limit the filter to resources classes/methods also annotated with the name binding annotation. If this is the case, then annotate the classes/methods you wan to go through that filter. If you want everything to go through the filter, then forget the annotation altogether. Just get rid of it

Comment: @peeskillet I'm impressed! I don't know if this is smart or stupid. Thanks for this.  Post that as an answer!

Comment: @peeskillet I only needed to bind it to any method/class to make it work. I stopped the moment it gave me the error. Its more of a warning than an error to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really an error that will stop JAX-RS from working. It's more of just a warning (specific to that editor).

Name Binding should only be used when you want to limit the filter to resources classes/methods also annotated with the name binding annotation. If this is the case, then annotate the classes/methods you want to go through that filter. If you want everything to go through the filter, then forget the annotation altogether. Just get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

These types of error are not really big errors. For this type of error on JAX-RS we can mark it as a warning or ignore it at all.

For Eclipse, go to `Window > Preferences > Jboss Tools > JAX-RS > JAX-RS Validator > JAX-RS Name Bindings` and set `Missing @Retention annotation` to something other than "*Error*". (Yes, the preference name is misleading).

(To customize it for a specific project, click on `Configure Project Specific Settings...` in the top right corner)

Comment: What specific validation message should be configured as 'Warning' in the "JAX-RS Validator" dialog?